# "Operation on two GEOMETRIES with different SRIDs"

Tags: postgis

I have this query that search for the nearest 5 stations (5km at max) from the location that I'm selecting (com.id):

```
SELECT est.name as nombre, '5km' AS metodo FROM vectorial.meteorologicasccg est 
JOIN vectorial.dpa_comuna com ON  com.id = :id 
WHERE ST_Contains(ST_Buffer( ST_Centroid( com.thegeom ), 5000 ), st_transform( est.the_geom, 3857 ) )
```

It works ok. But, in case that I have no results, I will go for the nearest, and I'm trying to do it with this:

```
SELECT est.name as nombre, 'mascercano' AS metodo, ST_Distance( ST_Centroid( com.thegeom ), st_transform( est.the_geom, 3857 ) ) AS distancia 
FROM vectorial.meteorologicasccg est 
JOIN vectorial.dpa_comuna com ON  com.id = :id 
ORDER BY ST_Distance( ST_Centroid( com.thegeom ), st_transform( est.the_geom, 3857 ) ) ASC LIMIT 1
```

But I got this error:

```
"Operation on two GEOMETRIES with different SRIDs"
```

I'm trying to replicate this:

I have this query, it calculates the minimum distance of the center of a 'radio' search ( a circunference) and some target. It works:

```
SELECT est.name as nombre, 'mascercano' AS metodo, ST_Distance( ST_Centroid( st_geometryfromtext('POINT(".$center[0]." ".$center[1].")', 3857) ), st_transform( est.the_geom, 3857 ) ) AS distancia 
FROM vectorial.meteorologicasccg est ORDER BY ST_Distance( ST_Centroid( st_geometryfromtext('POINT(".$center[0]." ".$center[1].")', 3857) ), st_transform( est.the_geom, 3857 ) ) ASC LIMIT 1
```

This one use a different type of search, but it's working.

What I'm doing wrong in the query?

I'm very new to GIS.

Comment: Now I'm using `st_transform( est.the_geom, 32719 )`now it works. I said that with 3857 was working but it wasn't, I checked some old code and est.the_geom need to by 32719. I solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second query you did not transform the geometry to the same SRID. Try:

```
SELECT est.name as nombre, 'mascercano' AS metodo, ST_Distance( ST_Centroid( 
ST_Transform(com.thegeom,3857)), st_transform( est.the_geom, 3857 ) ) AS 
distancia FROM vectorial.meteorologicasccg est  JOIN vectorial.dpa_comuna  com 
ON  com.id = id 
ORDER BY   
ST_Distance(ST_Centroid(ST_Transform(com.thegeom,3587 ), st_transform( 
est.the_geom, 3857 ) ) ASC LIMIT 1
```

I don't see why you want to join on the ID. Have a look at this [page](http://www.bostongis.com/PrinterFriendly.aspx?content_name=postgis_nearest_neighbor) explaining several ways to perform a nearest neighbour join in Postgis. One of the outlined methods is:

```
SELECT f1.id As ref_id, f1.ref_name, f2.id As knearest_id,  
f2.ref_name As  knearest_name 
FROM foo As f1, foo As f2   
WHERE f1.id = 1 and f1.id <> f2.id 
AND ST_DWithin(f1.the_geom, f2.the_geom, 500)   
ORDER BY ST_Distance(f1.the_geom,f2.the_geom) 
LIMIT 10
```

Do not forget to add a spatial index on larger data sets and transform your geometry column into a projected coordinate system for the distance to make sense.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your first query is that you are only transforming one of the geoms into a different SRID.

Try replacing`WHERE ST_Contains(ST_Buffer( ST_Centroid( com.thegeom ), 5000 ), st_transform( est.the_geom, 3857 ) )` in the first query with

`Where ST_Contains(st_transform(ST_Buffer( ST_Centroid(com.thegeom), 5000), 3857), st_transform(est.the_geom, 3857) )`